# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javafx.application.Platform.startup(java.lang.Runnable)

Tags: javafx, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, tornadofx

I have a tornadofx app that I've moved from an earlier version of Kotlin and Kotlin Coroutines to the latest (1.3 and 1.0.1) When I run it I get the above exception on this line

```
button("Click to calculate") {
}.setOnAction {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.UI) { }
}
```

It's the call to 'launch' that causes the exception. This all worked in the release I was running on previously.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/816). Either wait for `1.0.2` where it is hopefully fixed or downgrade to `1.0.0` at the moment where it still works. I did the latter and it suffices to update all the other stuff that needs to be updated (coroutines, etc.), in case you are coming from a pre-1.3-version.